# Cracking passwords with DES algorithm given hash and salt

Tags: python, hash, openssl, cracking, hashcat

I am given a hash ("1u9Tc6HX") and the salt ("Ff"), and I am told to crack the password knowing that it has been hashed with DES algorithm. Using hashcat, I have known that the password is ("michael") and I am now trying to hash this password in order to compare it with the hash given.
However, I have tried using (openssl enc) command but it always asks me for the password used for encryption, what I am not given, so I don't know how to hash ("michael") using DES and salt ("Ff") and get ("1u9Tc6HX"). I am open to change the procedure and try other things in case you think is easier to crack by other way. (I am working with python)
Any comment and help is appreciated.

Pd:
Example: Ff1u9Tc6HXxJo
Enunciate: The password has been hashed using the DES algorithm. The entry consists
in 13 printable ASCII characters, where the two first characters represent the salt.
With DES, only the first 8 characters of the password are used.

Comment: DES is an encryption algorithm (block cipher) and doesn't provide hashing by default. However it can be used creatively to build a hash algorithm. That is what the answer shows. DES is only used as a basis in the Unix crypt algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Passlib](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) is a popular library for password hashing:

```
>>> import passlib.hash
>>> passlib.hash.des_crypt.hash('michael', salt='Ff')
'Ff1u9Tc6HXxJo'
```